# How can I find existing node by name and append some extra values to the existing ArrayList in Firebase Database?

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building an app using Firebase where I am checking for presence of certain values in the node and if it is present I am just adding to it instead of creating a new node.
But  when I try to implement the same its actually implementing infinite query and database getting filled up

For simplicity I am including that portion of the code that is causing problem:

Here the `else` coode means as the data node is already present in the database I am appending.

```
else {    
    user u=new user(SharedPrefManager.getmInstnce(ChatList.this).getUsername(),SharedPrefManager.getmInstnce(ChatList.this).getmail());

    for(int l=0;l<grpar.size();l++){
        if(grpar.get(l).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(grpname)){
            index=l;
            break;
        }
    }
    Log.i("Checking QUERY","Value exist!!!!  in  "+ index);
    grpar.get(index).getGrpMembers().add(u);
    Group grp=new Group(grpname,grpar.get(index).getGrpMembers());
    grpRef.push().setValue(grp).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful())
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ChatList.this,MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Id","none");
                intent.putExtra("Name",grpname);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(ChatList.this,"Data Not Added Completely",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

From the moment I applied the following logic it started behaving abnormally:

```
for(int l=0;l<grpar.size();l++){
    if(grpar.get(l).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(grpname)){
        index=l;
        break;
    }
}
```

I am also attaching the DB structure:

[image: I am also attaching the DB structure-]

I cannot figure out where the error is ! Any help is appreciated

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Whenever I am running the code..nodes are being added to the firebase database nodes infinitely... @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo I have also updated the question